# RegEx - Match on XML declarations when the version # is not "1.0"

Tags: c#, regex, xml

I want to use RegEx for this.

I need to find errant XML declarations AND anything that is not version 1.0

The following would be valid matches: 
**Bad declaration**

```
<? xml ver="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

**Bad declaration**

```
<?xml version="1.0' encoding=UTF-8>
```

**Bad declaration**

```
<?xml ?>
```

**Bad declaration (doesn't start on the first line)**

```
 .....   
<? xml ver="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

**Version 1.1 (single quotes)**

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

**Version 1.1 (double quotes)**

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

**Erroneous version #**

```
<?xml version='999999' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

**Version 1.1 (multi-line)** - Not sure if multi-line formatting is allowed but I've seen it done and I need to check for it.

> ```
> <?xml 
> version="1.1" 
> encoding="UTF-8" 
> standalone="no" ?>
> ```

---

We only want matches on *invalid XML* declarations **OR** XML declarations with a *version other than 1.0*

The following as valid XML 1.0 declarations. These should never return a match:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?> 
>
> <?xml version= "1.0" encoding= 'UTF-8' standalone= "no" ?>
>
> <?xml 
> version="1.0" 
> encoding="UTF-8" 
> standalone="no" ?>
> ```

Comment: *Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.* — which language or tool you are using?

Comment: Good catch! Thanks! I added a C# tag.

Comment: Yes, newlines are allowed anywhere spaces are allowed. Also, spaces are allowed in places where none of your examples have them, for example around the "=" signs.

Comment: Both `standalone` and new-line-as-space are valid in XML 1.0. Why are they excluded?

Comment: @kennytm I apologize if I missed a possible example. It was not intentional.

Comment: @user3541092 I mean the last two examples, why are they not valid?

Comment: @kennytm They are valid. I updated the question. I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML 1.0's [XML declaration grammar](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-XMLDecl) is:

```
XMLDecl      ::=    '<?xml' VersionInfo EncodingDecl? SDDecl? S? '?>'
VersionInfo  ::=    S 'version' Eq ("'" VersionNum "'" | '"' VersionNum '"')
Eq           ::=    S? '=' S?
VersionNum   ::=    '1.0'
EncodingDecl ::=    S 'encoding' Eq ('"' EncName '"' | "'" EncName "'" )
EncName      ::=    [A-Za-z] ([A-Za-z0-9._] | '-')*
SDDecl       ::=    S 'standalone' Eq (("'" ('yes' | 'no') "'") | ('"' ('yes' | 'no') '"'))
S            ::=    (#x20 | #x9 | #xD | #xA)+
```

This can be trivally converted to C#'s regex notation, which we could write the regex that **matches the valid declaration**:

```
new Regex(@"
\A<\?xml
[ \t\n\r]+version[ \t\n\r]*=[ \t\n\r]*([""'])1\.0\1
(?:[ \t\n\r]+encoding[ \t\n\r]*=[ \t\n\r]*([""'])[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9._-]*\2)?
(?:[ \t\n\r]+standalone[ \t\n\r]*=[ \t\n\r]*([""'])(?:yes|no)\3)?
[ \t\n\r]*
\?>
", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
```

And this can be inverted using a negative look-ahead to make it **match if a valid declaration is missing**.

```
new Regex(@"
\A(?!<\?xml
[ \t\n\r]+version[ \t\n\r]*=[ \t\n\r]*([""'])1\.0\1
(?:[ \t\n\r]+encoding[ \t\n\r]*=[ \t\n\r]*([""'])[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9._-]*\2)?
(?:[ \t\n\r]+standalone[ \t\n\r]*=[ \t\n\r]*([""'])(?:yes|no)\3)?
[ \t\n\r]*
\?>)
", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
```

(I've used back-reference to simplify the regex but they are not necessary)

Note that when it match, it will just match the beginning of the string, it won't match the invalid declaration for you. You could add a `(<[^>]*>)` after the lookahead if you really need a non-empty match.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of the regex-expression, that satisfies your conditions:

```
(<\?xml\s+version="1\.0"\s+encoding="[^"]+"\s+standalone="((yes)|(no))"\s*\?>)
```

To see an [example](https://regex101.com/r/PZwJ8K/1), and debug your expressions, I recommend the online [regex101](https://regex101.com/) tester.

And here it is my C# function example, which returns `true` if the file content starts with the right from your point of view declaration:

```cs
private bool ValidateDeclaration(string fileContent)
{
    var re = Regex.Match(fileContent, @"(<\?xml\s+version=""1\.0""\s+encoding=""[^""]+""\s+standalone=""((yes)|(no))""\s*\?>)");
    return re.Success && re.Groups[1].Index == 0;
}
```

**Update** (After your edit of the question)**:**
There are an infinite number of wrong expressions, so does not correspond to everything, except the part which corresponds to, just rename function and negate results=). If you want allow spaces, just add `[ ]*` anywhere where they can stand

```cs
private bool IsInvalidDeclaration(string fileContent)
{
    var re = Regex.Match(fileContent, @"(<\?xml\s+version=""1\.0""\s+encoding=""[^""]+""\s+standalone=""((yes)|(no))""\s*\?>)");
    return !(re.Success && re.Groups[1].Index == 0);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I usually just skip reading the identification line :

```
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            reader.ReadLine();
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
```

Comment: That's very poor practice. There is no requirement for the XML declaration to be followed by a newline character, and in machine-generated XML it often isn't.

Comment: It is the only work around for the Net Library not handling all the identification options.

Comment: If you really have to strip off the XML declaration then it's surely better to look for the "?>" which will always be there, rather than the newline, which won't. And shouldn't you be checking that an XML declaration exists before removing it?

Comment: My code is very simple and will work 99% of the time.  Why add complications that aren't necessary.  Searching for ?> would require reading more of the file and with huge xml that doesn't make a lot of sense.  My solution will work nicely with XmlReader as well as XDocument.

Comment: I've never worked in an environment where 99% reliability is acceptable.

Comment: it will work 100% when the is a return at end of identification.

Comment: And will fail 100% when there isn't.

Comment: Write the code yourself and you will see the added complexity making it work 100%.  It is not worth the extra code if it is not necessary when there is already a cr.

Comment: Just remind me never to employ a programmer with that mindset.

Comment: I'm an engineer that knows when practical solutions are the correct approach and never writes spaghetti code as a kludge.